# Referring a particular website, should I use the noun adjunct or the genitive/possessive?

Tags: possessives, internet, attributive-nouns, social-media

I'm wondering if there are any guidelines about using the noun adjunct or the possessive with a website and a company.

Should I write: `go to the Twitter website` or `go to Twitter's website`?

AFAIK both are grammatically correct, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, if it does come down to a stylistic choice, is there any reason to pick one camp over the other?

Comment: Both sound perfectly acceptable to me. The first sounds a bit more formal, which might be preferable in written instructions, if you want to be more professional. You can also provide the website's URL (for *x*, go to...)

Comment: `the website's URL` hmm, is that correct in the first place? :) I mean, I was taught that for genitive case we needed the owner of a property to be a person or institution or possibly a word representing a community of people like maybe Twitter representing the people behind it or people using it, but *website's URL*? Isn't it wrong to use genitive case between two inanimated objects?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you think of "Twitter". If Twitter according to you is a website created by a company, then "go to Twitter's website" is correct. If you do not take into consideration the fact that someone made Twitter, then "go to the Twitter website" is correct. Of course, in today's world, one usually says "go to Twitter", treating it like a physical location.