# "Germany's" or "German" Ministry of Defence?

Tags: apostrophe, possessive-s-vs-of, adjective-position

What are the rules for referring to a ministry (or any other department, organisation, etc) of a specific country? I found both on Google. Are the US and UK exceptions (as it's the US Ministry of Defence)?

Comment: related [A noun adjunct / the possessive case](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87591/a-noun-adjunct-the-possessive-case) and [Which form should be used for “student union”: singular, plural, possessive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200551/which-form-should-be-used-for-student-union-singular-plural-possessive)

Comment: Also [Referring a particular website, should I use the noun adjunct or the genitive/possessive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147676/referring-a-particular-website-should-i-use-the-noun-adjunct-or-the-genitive-po) and [Genitive case or attributive noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48234/genitive-case-or-attributive-noun)

Comment: Thanks. Very informative examples. Just, sometimes, too technical for non-native English speakers.

Comment: @Ben Welcome to EL&U, but the charter of this site is to serve *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*, so technical answers should not be surprising. There is a separate, sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) which may interest you; see e.g. *[Should I say “the park sitting area” or “the park's sitting area”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129216)* or *[Should I use “vehicle” or “vehicle's”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36945/)*